# android set margin programmatically

Tags: android

after i press a button, i would like to move a textfield programmatically from the actual position + 20 margin left.

this is my xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtField"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtField2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Seperator"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/Seperator"
        android:layout_marginRight="10p" />

    ....


</RelativeLayout>
```

i tried this code:

```
parameter = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
parameter.setMargins(30, 32, 10, 0); // left, top, right, bottom
txtField.setLayoutParams(parameter);
```

this works semi optimal.
is there an way to use all the values of an xml file and only change the margin left value programmatically?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try this code:

```
parameter =  (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) txtField.getLayoutParams();
parameter.setMargins(leftMargin, parameter.topMargin, parameter.rightMargin, parameter.bottomMargin); // left, top, right, bottom
txtField.setLayoutParams(parameter);
```

Comment: for xamarin , throws invalid cast exception.

Comment: Make sure you're using casting to the layout param of the widget's parent. For example, if the widget is in a ConstraintLayout, use ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.

Comment: If your Main Parent Layout is `LinearLayout` then use `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` as Parameter

Answer (score 24):

Yep,

Take for example the following method that updates the left margin of a given view:

```
public static void setMarginLeft(View v, int left) {
    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params =   
                                (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)v.getLayoutParams();
    params.setMargins(left, params.topMargin, 
                            params.rightMargin, params.bottomMargin);
}
```

Comment: This worked for me after trying a lot of other solutions. Thanks.

Comment: wished margins were in DP like everything else.  hate having to convert to pixels

Answer (score 9):

If you use kotlin, this can be simplified by creating an extension function

```
fun View.setMarginLeft(leftMargin: Int) {
  val params = layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams
  params.setMargins(left, params.topMargin, params.rightMargin, params.bottomMargin)
  layoutParams = params
}
```

Now all you need is a view, and this extension function can be used anywhere.

```
val textView = findViewById(R.id.textView)
val marginLeft = context.resources.getDimension(R.dimen.marginLeft).toInt()
textView.setMarginLeft(marginLeft)
```

Note: This extension function will leave all other margins intact, no margins will be overwritten

Answer (score 5):

You can also try

```
ImageView _circle=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams mlp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) _circle.getLayoutParams();
int _20 = (int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.image_margin); 
// Directly set 20
mlp.setMargins(_20, _20, _20, _20);
```

Answer (score 5):

*Extending* @enyciaa answer: by using Kotlin you can use extensions, but instead create one extension function for each margin side, you can use nullable value for all sides and then fill only values that's not null:

```
fun View.setMargin(
    leftMargin: Int? = null,
    topMargin: Int? = null,
    rightMargin: Int? = null,
    bottomMargin: Int? = null
) {
    val params = layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams

    params.setMargins(
        leftMargin ?: params.leftMargin,
        topMargin ?: params.topMargin,
        rightMargin ?: params.rightMargin,
        bottomMargin ?: params.bottomMargin
    )
    
    layoutParams = params
}
```

So if you want to set **only** left margin, you can do it by specifying parameter name like this:

```
textView.setMargin(leftMargin = marginValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

**This will work in Android 30**

```
val textView = TextView(this)
val layoutParams = ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(10, 10)
layoutParams.marginStart = 5
textView.layoutParams = layoutParams
```

To set padding -

```
textView.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use these few lines of code in kotlin

```
val params = your_view.layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams
params.setMargins(dpToPx(80, this), dpToPx(0, this), dpToPx(0, this), dpToPx(0, this))
```

Here is the code for the function dpToPx

```
private fun dpToPx(dp: Int, context: Context): Int {
    val density = context.resources.displayMetrics.density
    return (dp.toFloat() * density).roundToInt()
}
```

If you are using fragment, use `requireContext()` as parameter for context. From activity, use `this` as context like I have done